Trying to implement a constraint layout in Android Studio but build failing
Having an issue as I work through a tutorial on using constraint layout in Android Studio.
In the tutorial android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout is used but that is now deprecated.  As recommended I am attempting the transition to AndroidX.
This is the project level build.gradle.kts:
buildscript {
    repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}

plugins {
//    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    id("com.android.application") version "8.4.0" apply false
    id("com.chaquo.python") version "15.0.1" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "7.3.1" apply false
}

This is the module level build.gradle.kts:
  //  alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.chaquo.python")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.pythontestwithjavafix"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.pythontestwithjavafix"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        compileSdk = 34

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk{
            abiFilters += listOf("arm64-v8a","x86_64")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

chaquopy{
    defaultConfig{
        version = "3.10"
        pip{
            install("scipy")
            install("requests==2.24.0")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.navigation.fragment)
    implementation(libs.navigation.ui)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
//    implementation("com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4")
   implementation(libs.constraint.layout)
}

This is the activity_main.xml:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8E9CED"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textColor="#F8E115"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

On my first build attempt this error occurs:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.13.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:18-86
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-25:19 to override

So I then implemented the recommendation above and a new error occurs:
/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/PythonTestWithJavaFix/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-26:19 Error:
        tools:replace specified at line:5 for attribute tools:android.appComponentFactory, but no new value specified
/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/PythonTestWithJavaFix/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Validation failed, exiting

A search has turned up little other than the recommendation to move away from the android.support.* used in the tutorial and move to androidx which I did in activity_main.xml.  Interestingly, I checked the project tree and still see a reference to android.support.constraint.* in gradle/libs.versions.toml as follows:
[libraries]
constraint-layout = { module = "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout", version.ref = "constraintLayoutVersion" }

Could this be the problem?  If so, let me know how to fix.  I do not see a lot of discussion regarding the *.toml file but I may have missed it.  Please advise.  TIA.
So I am at a loss as to how to proceed.

Try this with your old code which has support library it will automatically handle the dependency issue


Appreciate the input.  I did see this option online when I searched for solutions, however, with the version I'm running (Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1), the 'Refactor' tab only has an option 'Migrate Packages and Classes' which points to two options 'JUnit (4.x -> 5.0)' and 'Create New Migration...'.  The latter seems relevant but I do not know how to create an AndroidX Migration on the fly with this option.  Maybe someone can clue me in?
